# e1000e Network Errors in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, intel-nuc

I'm having big issues with getting my onboard network cards to work with Ubuntu. I've tried clean installs of 16.04, 18.04 and 18.10, each version reports the cards as being unplugged.

I've tried tried the same ethernet cable and ethernet wall socket on a different computer without issue.

I'm currently on 16.04.1 and have installed the latest Intel drivers (v3.4.2.1) from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-?v=t) using the following commands :

```
sudo make install

modprobe e1000e
```

When I run

```
modinfo e1000e | grep version
```

I see that the version reported installed is

```
version:        3.4.2.1-NAPI
```

so i assume everything went well.

But after rebooting the network  cards still report themselves as being unplugged. WiFi works fine on the same computer.

[These](https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/tower/7039/SYS-7039A-i.cfm) are my computer specs if that helps.

None of the other threads I see here work, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep 'Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: It doesn't output anything, just puts me back at the prompt.

Comment: I made a typo `lspci -knn | grep 'Eth' -A3`

Comment: Here's the output :-

`b6:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X722 for 1GbE [8086:37d1] (rev 09)
 DeviceName: Intel Ethernet X722 
 Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Device [15d9:37d1]
 Kernel driver in use: i40e
 Kernel modules: i40e`



`b6:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X722 for 1GbE [8086:37d1] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Device [15d9:37d1]
 Kernel driver in use: i40e
 Kernel modules: i40e`